# Jasmine Failing Components on Create using pre-made spec.ts Files

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have decided to create unit tests for my Angular Material project. Right now, I am just testing to see if the pre-made spec.ts files for each component pass successfully. My project compiles and runs correctly. However, after running `ng test` and viewing the results in the Karma Runner. Almost all of my components seem to fail on their basic pre-made spec.ts files. The errors shown seem to be compiler errors but my project has no problem compiling.

Some of the errors:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<mat-form-field class="form-field wide">
```

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

I have noticed that these errors seem to include Angular Material, is it possible that my tests are not aware of the fact that Angular Material is installed?

Answer (score 1):

> I have noticed that these errors seem to include Angular Material, is it possible that my tests are not aware of the fact that Angular Material is installed?

Yes!

Each Jasmine test needs its own module declared with all dependencies. So you'll need to add your material modules to TestBed.

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MatToolbarModule, /*other required modules*/],
        declarations: [/*all component declarations*/]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Also, you might want consider using a Material module, which would contain Angular Material dependencies your application requires. For instance:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Then you can always import Material module in other modules/tests, this way you'll be able to manage dependencies easier.

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MaterialModule, /*other required modules*/],
        declarations: [/*all component declarations*/]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: Adding the Material component manually works, I tried to import a MaterialModule as a whole but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you create your own material module?